# How to show a child div on top parent div when the parent div's horizontal scroll is visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to show a child div with its 100% height on top of a parent div **when the parent div's horizontal scroll is visible**. Although initially, it seemed really straight-forward but have been struggling with it all the while.

Here's the markup https://codepen.io/ambarbs/pen/OwwojV

```css
.parent {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  color: white;
  /*   z-index: 0; */
}

.child {
  width: 400px;
}

.menu {
  height: 300px;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    I want to show the orange .menu DIV on top of this DIV.
    Is it possible when the horizontal scroll is visible?
  </div>
  <div class='menu'></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** The *menu* is actually a context-menu and should always show ideally show on top of the scrollbar as well.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more details? The *on-top* part is a bit confusing. Sometimes when words are scarce, a drawing could help understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS you can do it by:

- Set `.parent` to `position: relative;`
- Set `.child` to `position: absolute;`
- Set `.menu` to `position: sticky; left: 0;`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}

.menu {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(255, 120, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    I want to show the orange .menu DIV on top of this DIV.
    Is it possible when the horizontal scroll is visible?
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>MENU</div>
</div>
```

Beware that **Position Sticky** is [not supported by any IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) browser (of course)

---

#### SOLUTION FOR IE 9, 10, 11

A bit of JS could help you to handle older browsers.
Basically, on scroll it uses `translateX` to set the `.menu` position:

```js
const transX = (ev, el) => {
  ev.target.querySelector(el).style.transform = `translateX(${ev.target.scrollLeft}px)`;
};

document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("scroll", ev => transX(ev, ".menu"));
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}

.menu {
  position: relative; /* Set to "sticky" and remove JS if you don't care about IE */
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(255, 120, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    I want to show the orange .menu DIV on top of this DIV.
    Is it possible when the horizontal scroll is visible?
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>MENU</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Roko, thanks for the solution. The menu height can be more than the parent div's height. And in that case, it should on top of the scrollbar.

I have added some more info.

The *menu* is actually a context-menu and should always show ideally show on top of the scrollbar as well.

Comment: @ambar you cannot pull elements outside of overflow. Instead place your contextmenu outside of `.parent` with position fixed (and hidden initially). On `.parent` click get the `pageX, pageY` coordinates, minus the `offsetParent().left` and `.top` positions.

Answer (score -1):

[Solution](https://codepen.io/thefewunshaken/pen/gjjBjG)

Set the position property of the desired child to `fixed`. That way, its position is based on the browser window instead of the parent. For a `fixed` `<div>` with no content, you must specify the `width` and `height` properties. If you want the width the same as the parent, you can use the `inherit` value.

```
.menu{
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: inherit;
  background: orange;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```